# NumberFormat for CAD Currency not Right

Tags: javascript, currency

I am using `Intl.NumberFormat` and when I set the currency to CAD with an English locale, I am getting `CA$5.00`. I thought the symbols would be something `$ or Can$ or C$ or CAD` I just threw up a simple codepen https://codepen.io/jrock2004/pen/MMKqQq?editors=1010

```
const price = 5,
  locale = 'en-US',
  currency = 'CAD';

const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat (locale, {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: currency,
});

const formattedPrice = formatter.format (price);
```

Am I doing something wrong or maybe nothing is wrong at all? Thanks

Comment: What were you expecting?
Notice that if you change the locale, the displayed formatted price changes. (try en-CA and fr-CA for instance)

Comment: I would of expected something like C$5.00 or Can$5.00. I notice that the format changes but I believe for CAD with en-US the format is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript engine V8 uses ICU for currency(and other locale) formatting.
And ICU uses CLDR. In cldr we have a list of defined alternative names [here](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/40282e73293ac881fddba9c6cd6fb1baab6bc27b/common/main/root.xml).
So when we set locale as US(`en_US`) and we want us dollars then the symbol is $. But for the same locale we can get different dollars so in order to distinguish it CDLR returns different symbols. Same would be if you set locale to `en_CA` and currency to `CAD` then we get the symbol `$` because Canadians refer to Canadian dollars as dollars(no surprise here :) ) And for `locale = 'en-CA', currency = 'USD'` we would get US$1.00.

There are several alternative dollar symbols in CLDR(AUD - A$, BRL - R$ and few others).

Also if we check the documentation for [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)
currencyDisplay options can be `symbol`, `code` or `name`. If you pass `code` you get `CAD 1.00` and if you pass `symbol` you get `CA$ 1.00`.

TLDR; Js uses ICU that uses CDLR that returns `CA$` for your case.

Comment: So to get C$100 what should I set for locale and currency? I set locale='en-CA' and currency='CAD' and I am getting $100 only. Thanks in advance .

Comment: I the moment i don't know if this is possible. if "CA$ 100" would be enough you could set the locale to 'en-US'

Answer (score 0):

So to get c$100 I didn't find any direct solution but this helped me,

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD', currencyDisplay: 'symbol' }).format(1000).replace('A', ''));
```